# How to easily filter from csv with python?

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following CSV file:

```
User ID   Name        Application  

001       Ajohns      ABI
002       Fjerry      Central
900       Xknight     RFC
300       JollK       QDI
078       Demik       Central
```

Is there some easy way to (import this into some data structure)? and/or be able to easily perform the following operations in python:

```
1) Get all user IDs with Application=Central
2) Get the row where name="FJerry" then extract say the "userid" value from
3) Give me the filtered rows for those with "Application=Central" so I can write out to CSV
4) Give me all the rows where Name="Ajohn", and Application="ABI" such that I could easy do a len() to count them up?
```

Is there some python library or what is the easiest way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Have you looked at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial using [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). You need to pass `excel-tab` as the dialect since your fields are tab delimited.

`rows` is a list of dictionaries.

```
>>> with open(r'd:\file.csv','rb') as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(f,dialect='excel-tab')
...     rows = list(reader)
...
>>> [x['User ID'] for x in rows if x['Application'] == 'Central']
['002', '078']
```